# How to handle multiple radio button groups in one component in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to send list of selected radio button ids from multiple radio button groups on clicking send button,

**My problem:**
I am getting selected radio button from backend , then I should be able to change the radio button and send back to backend. but when I try to change the radio button it is not working.

**What I did not understand:**
How to handle the on change function, normally on change we can change the state but to change the state on load we should grab the values radio buttons. Finally I got struck here, not understanding how to move forward.

Here is the wireframe and code snippet:

[image: wireframe]

```js
function CardsList(props) {
  const cards = props.cards;
  return (
    <div>
      {cards.map((card, idx) => (
       <div>
         {card.cardName}
          {
            card.options.map((lo,idx) => (
              <li key={idx}>
              <input
                 className="default"
                 type="radio"
                 name={card.cardName}
                 checked={lo.selected}
             />))
          }
         <div>
       ))}
   </div>
  );
}
//array of cards coming from the backend
const cards = [
{cardName:'card1',options:[{radioName:'card1-radio1',selected:'true'},
                          {radioName:'card1-radio2',selected:'false'}]},
  {cardName:'card2',options:[{radioName:'card2-radio1',selected:'true'},
                          {radioName:'card2-radio2',selected:'false'}]}
];
ReactDOM.render(
  <CardsList cards={cards} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an object as a lookup table that holds the group names as keys.
On each change you will need to find the relevant group with the relevant option and set the new state accordingly.

**Important!** - one thing to notice here, is that i changed the type of the `selected` property from a `String` to a `Boolean`. this will let me handle the conditions like this:

```
<input checked={option.selected} />
```

If you can't change it to a `Boolean` then you will need to handle the condition like this:

```
<input checked={option.selected === 'true'} />
```

Here is a running example:

```js
//array of cards coming from the backend
const data = [
  {
    cardName: 'card1', options: [{ radioName: 'card1-radio1', selected: true },
    { radioName: 'card1-radio2', selected: false }]
  },
  {
    cardName: 'card2', options: [{ radioName: 'card2-radio1', selected: true },
    { radioName: 'card2-radio2', selected: false }]
  }
];


class CardsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cards: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // mimic an async server call
      this.setState({ cards: data });
    }, 1000);
  }

  onInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    const nexState = cards.map(card => {
      if (card.cardName !== target.name) return card;
      return {
        ...card,
        options: card.options.map(opt => {
          const checked = opt.radioName === target.value;
          return {
            ...opt,
            selected: checked
          }
        })
      }
    });
    this.setState({ cards: nexState })
  }

  onSubmit = () => { console.log(this.state.cards) };

  render() {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          cards.length < 1 ? "Loading..." :
            <div>
              {cards.map((card, idx) => (
                <ul>
                  {card.cardName}
                  {
                    card.options.map((lo, idx) => {
                      return <input
                        key={idx}
                        type="radio"
                        name={card.cardName}
                        value={lo.radioName}
                        checked={!!lo.selected}
                        onChange={this.onInputChange}
                      />

                    })
                  }
                </ul>
              ))
              }
              < button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Print Cards</button>
            </div>
        }

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CardsList />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you can't change them is because of their current checked state which you are setting here:

```
<input
  className="default"
  type="radio"
  name={card.cardName}
  checked={lo.selected}
/>
```

An approach I have used for this exact scenario is storing the component's state (from the server) in my component's state (`this.state`), passing the state to the element: `checked={this.state.isChecked}`, and updating the element's state `onClick`.

Example:

```
class CardsList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {isChecked: false};
    this.inputOnClick = this.inputOnClick.bind(this);
  }
  //fetch data from server
  fetchData(){
    fetch('/api')
      .then(res => res.json())
      //this will be our initial state
      .then(res => this.setState(res))
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }
  //change radio button state on click
  inputOnClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //invert state value
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {isChecked: !prevState.isChecked});
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <input
        type="radio"
        checked={this.state.isChecked}
        onClick={this.inputOnClick}
       />
      )
   }
}
```

> this answer may work with single radio button group , but i am facing
>   problem with multiple radio buttons with in multiple radio button
>   groups.if you see the array of cards , how does it know which radio
>   button group it belongs to.

We can modify the state based on the radio button's name.

Let's save all of your cards in your component's state. I know the cards are retrieved from the server and will be saved using `setState` but I am writing it like this for visual purposes.

```
this.state = {cards: [
  { cardName:'card1',
  options:[
    {radioName:'card1-radio1',selected:true},
    {radioName:'card1-radio2',selected:false}
   ]
  },
  { cardName:'card2',
    options:[
      {radioName:'card2-radio1',selected:true},
      {radioName:'card2-radio2',selected:false}
     ]
    }
]}
```

Now when we click on a radio button, we will use that radio button's name to update the state where it needs to be updated. Since React state needs to be immutable, we will create a deep copy of the state, modify it, and then set the state with it.

```
inputOnClick(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var thisRadioBtn = e.target.name;
  //make a deep copy of the state
  const stateCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.cards));
  //go through state copy and update it
  stateCopy.forEach(card => {
    card.options.forEach(option => {
      if(option.radioName === thisRadioBtn){
        //invert value
        //make sure the values are booleans
        option.selected = !option.selected;
      }
    });
  });
  //update the components state
  this.setState({cards: stateCopy});
}
```

Comment: this answer may work with single radio button group , but  i am facing problem with multiple radio buttons with in multiple radio button groups.if you see the array of cards , how does it know which radio button group it belongs to.

Comment: what if we have a dynamic state and we dont know how many cards will get from backend ?
i am trying out at my end. probably i will post once i get the perfect one.

Comment: @user8208248 as long as you're saving the fetched data to your state, you will be good.

Answer (score 2):

In June 2022, I'm facing a similar issue with you. My solution is just add tag `<form>` on both sections with no OnSubmit or action on it.